# How to take the derivative of a tangent vector.

Tags: calculus

Find the tangent vector r(t) at the indicated point
and parametrize the tangent line at that point.

$r(t) = cos(π)ti + sin(π)tj + tk$ at $t = 2.$

For this question I know one must take the derivative of this equation r'(t). Which I did and I got 0 +0 + k. What baffles me is that this is not what they want and they got -πsin(π) which makes no sense since if you take the derivative of a pi number you will get 0. What special formula does one use to take the derivative of this problem?

Comment: Do you mean $cos(\pi t)$ and $sin(\pi t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$r'(t)=(-\pi\sin\pi t,\pi\cos\pi t,1), \enspace\text{hence}\quad r'(2)=(0,\pi,1).$$

Comment: So one must assume that pi is also a variable.

Comment: I beg your pardon? Why that? I only used  the chain rule for derivation.

Comment: Could you not have used derivative substitution to derive your answer?

Comment: I don't think so. How could you obtain thesecond coordinates? Note the chain rule is simply appplied with a linear substitution, an elementary case.

Comment: I am just trying to see how when you plug in 2 for r't you got (0,π,1). I would get (0,-2π,1)?

Comment: No, since $\cos 2\pi=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative vector is $$(-\pi\sin\pi t,\pi\cos\pi t,1)$$

It should be evaluated at $t=2,$ So the three vector components are

$$(0, \pi,1) $$